# If $ P(X \geq a) \leq \frac{E(X)}{a} $ what is $P(X < a)$? (Markov's Inequality)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Markov's Inequality states that if $X \geq 0$ and $a > 0$, then

$$ P(X \geq a) \leq \frac{E(X)}{a} $$

From this inequality, how do I get $P(X < a)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $P(X<a) = 1-P(X\geq a)$. Hence
$$P(X<a)\geq 1-\frac{E(X)}{a}$$
Not sure if this is very helpful.